# Kendo Grid Wrapper Call sync with method Read

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

We have Tabs and in every Tab has a Grid. We need some times updating two grids from client, but we want that call to Server was syncronous. We don't find async property or similar property in Kendo().Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<....>()
    .Name("..." + Model)
    .DataSource(data=>data.Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("action", "controllerGrid", new { id = Model }))
    .ServerOperation(false)
```

Comment: ajax is short for asynchronous JavaScript and XML, so its already send asynchronous request to your server, you should check your server code if its already handle asynchronous request from client

Answer (score 0):

We want put property async = false, like in next sample, but from wrapper kendo().grid<..>:

```
var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            async: false,
            },
        },
    },
});
```